# How to start AngularJS module without HTML page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in my browser extension project.

In the background.js (code of extension that run in background) I create a module that has *run block*.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

myModule.run(function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Normally, when I want to start module I just put ng-app in some HTML tag

```
<body ng-app="phonecatApp">
```

But this time there's no HTML page. How can I start the module ?

Comment: What do you want to use AngularJS for if you don't have HTML? o.O

Comment: You has a point. Actually my extension project also has a html popup which get much benefit from using AngularJS. 

For background scope I think at least AngularJS help code to be more modular that easy to test.

Comment: If there's no HTML you don't use AngularJS. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may help you if you have a look at one of Egghead's tutorial: [Unit Testing "Hello World"](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-hello-world) which may give you some idea of how to put angularjs machinery running without any html files.